# Convert date strings using lubridate but without daylight time adjustments

Tags: r, lubridate

My main question is further below.
Converting dates from character using lubridate::mdy_hms. I got a "1 failed to parse" error on my Mac (Yosemite, RStudio v1.1.453, R v3.3.3, Lubridate v1.7.4). But not on Ubuntu. Read that date/timezone quirks are platform specific so I let it slide. Revisiting this weekend, I tracked it down, on the Mac:

```
library(lubridate)
mdy_hms("03/11/2018 02:25:00 AM", tz="America/New_York")
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# 1 failed to parse.
```

March 11, 2018 was a time-change night in NY. Not sure if others can replicate this but - why is it NA? Losing information. On Ubuntu, the date parses to: "2018-03-11 01:25:00 EDT". Which brings me to my main question.

The dates, as best I can tell, are printed adjusting for EST/EDT, so adjusted time of 1:25 AM is not accurate. Leaving out tz="America/New_York" defaults to tz=UTC. Is there a way to convert the dates either (a) without adding/subtracting an hour (for 2:00:00 to 2:59:59AM times), (b) just leave out the time zone altogether?